# How does the u and r prefixes work with strings in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, rawstring, unicode-literals

I know that we can use the r(raw string) and u(unicode) flags before a string to get what we might actually desired. However, I am wondering how these do work with strings. I tried this in the IDLE:

```
a = r"This is raw string and \n will come as is"
print a
# "This is raw string and \n will come as is"
help(r)
# ..... Will get NameError
help(r"")
# Prints empty
```

How Python knows that it should treat the `r` or `u` in the front of a string as a flag? Or as string literals to be specific? If I want to learn more about what are the string literals and their limitations, how can I learn them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `u` and `r` prefixes are a part of the string literal, as defined in the python grammar. When the python interpreter parses a textual command in order to understand what the command does, it reads `r"foo"` as a single string literal with the value `"foo"`. On the other hand, it reads `b"foo"` as a single bytes literal with an equivalent value.

For more information, you can refer to the [literals section](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) in python's documentation. Also, python has an `ast` module, that allows you to explore the way python parses commands.